# Getting background and text color

Tags: color, backgrounds

I need to get the background and text color of an `article` type of document. I need it to to set some stuff in a `pgfplots`.
In `beamer`, I can read `normal text.fg` and `normal text.bg` and set, for instance, `\fill = normal text.fg`. How do I do the same with `article`? (and possibly with both `beamer` and `article`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no coloring mechanism built into the standard Latex classes; instead, coloring is done using packages like `pagecolor` and `background`. Accordingly, there is no standard way to obtain the actual rendered colors.